# Can we get the number of bots/users in jda?

Tags: java, discord-jda

I want to get the number of bots, number of users, and the number of members in a server. I know how to get the total number of members. So to get the number of bots/users, we could eaither fin the number of users or bots and then subtract it from the total number of members.

```
event.getGuild().getMemberCount() // Gets the total number of memebers in the server
```

Is there a way to get the number of users/bots.
Also, is there any way to get the number of people (and their names) with a specific role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Guild.getMemberCount()` method extracts the number of members in the guild from its available information, so there's no method to separate the count of members and bots, but you can count them separately iterating over them.

i.e:

```java
event.getGuild().loadMembers().onSuccess(members -> {
    int users = 0;
    int bots = 0;
    for(Member member: members){
        if (member.getUser().isBot())
            bots++;
        else
            users++;
    }
});
```

Note that in this code `Guild.loadMembers()` is used, which is a method that **requires** `GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS` to be enabled both on your bot's panel in Discord and in the JDA's build. Also, since this method returns a Task object, you need to handle it using a [lambda function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), once JDA fetches the whole list of members, you'll be able to iterate over it, in this example I'm using a for each loop.

Another thing to note is that the scope of these variables `users` and `bots` is exclusive to the lambda function inside the `onSuccess()`, so in my experience, I would recommend returning or replying to the event inside this function, leaving no other statements below this code, that way you avoid having two messy logic flows.